# Importance and Worshiping of Tulasi-devi in every resident

Tags: puranas

> I read an article of Srimati Tulasi-devi [(Reference)](http://www.vrindavan-dham.com/worshiping-tulasi/) and its importance also. Amazing and awesome.
>
> I want to know

`1. there is any other historical incidents about the Tulasi Madam in Hinduism and puranas.`

`2. And how Tulasi related to only in Lord Vishnu (Perumal) temples giving as theertam (holy water)`

> Could you please anyone can explain in brief with source articles.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer  **Mattapaliyil malarnda Paramporul** a tamil book by Lakshmi Narasimhachar in which it has been mentioned in srivaikundam a tulsi plant is found next to 10 other plants.Lord Narasimha telling to Thayar Rajyalakshmi in mattapali [in Andhra] how there will be tulsi plants in srivaikundam and how the fragrance come from that. If Krishna is offered a tulsi leaf he is the most satisfied. Based on this our ancestors planted tulsi plant in the house on the maadams by lighting a lamp in the evening and putting a kolam in the morning. Like Lord shiva is fond of Bilva leaf Lord Vishnu is fond of Tulsi leaf. Tulsi leaf should not be plucked in a hard manner. It should be softly plucked that too after bath in the mornings within 8 am only. Tulsi gayatri is **TULASI PATRAYE VITMAHE  MAHA LAKSHMAICHA DEEMAHE   THANNO TULASI PRACHODAYAATH**.